# What is the default root password for Zabbix Appliance 3.0?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, login, zabbix

I can't seem to find the default password for the root user on a fresh installation of Zabbix Appliance 3.0. Tried many common default passwords, but non worked.

Also tried other usernames that might work (like `zabbix` or `admin`) without luck.

Comment: Do you Google? - https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appliance

Comment: Actually, the answer below helped me, since I did not realize usernames in Zabbix are case sensitive!  So admin/zabbix was not working, but Admin/zabbix does work.

Comment: @joeqwerty The fun part is that I've found this question as the first search result from DuckDuckGo. So at this time, this question actually is useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Version 3:

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appliance

States that the default username and password for the front-end is:

```
Admin
zabbix
```

and for the console it is

```
appliance
zabbix
```

Comment: unfortunately on a german keybord you have to type yabbix to get zabbix for the password

Answer (score 9):

For Version 4 and 4.2 (2019)

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/appliance
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/appliance

Frontend username is:

Admin (with capital A)

password is:

zabbix